# Apache2-mod-ruid2 doesn't work

Tags: server, apache2, 16.04

I set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server with Apache2 and PHP7 cgi.
So far so good but as soon as I install ruid2

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-ruid2
```

Apache stops to work properly. I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when I try to access the server and the 
error Apache log read:

```
child pid 9252 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

What's wrong with the ruid2 module ?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue, even when the module is compiled from source.

To give some more debugging information, I started apache like this:

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars; strace /usr/sbin/apache2 -X -e info -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

The important part happens when apache gets the first request:

```
    clone(child_stack=0x7f0d483d8f70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f0d483d99d0, tls=0x7f0d483d9700, child_tidptr=0x7f0d483d99d0) = 8681
    rt_sigtimedwait(~[ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL SEGV USR2 PIPE CONT STOP SYS RTMIN RT_1], NULL, NULL, 8

<< WAITING FOR HTTP REQUEST >>

    ) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
    --- SIGRT_1 {si_signo=SIGRT_1, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=8679, si_uid=33} ---
    setgroups(1, [33])                      = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
    futex(0x7f0d4ebf1d9c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
    futex(0x7f0d47bd7c10, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
    +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

During the setgroups we now get "Operation not permitted".

This seems to happen if you use mpm_worker or mpm_event, with mpm_prefork it works fine.
Based on how these mpm's work it might be logical, except that we have been using mod_ruid2 in combination with mpm_worker on most of our shared hosting servers for years without any problem (12.04 and 14.04).

Comment: Thanks for this information.
On my Ubuntu server 14.04 I use suphp which work fine, but I had to turn to ruin2 as the suphp project is no longer existing and therefore is not available on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have no experience with ruin2 and I have to say it doesn't start very well.

I think I'll give up ruin2 and turn to fastcgi and phpfpm, but so far I've found almost nothing about how to install and configure them on Ubuntu 16.04.
Is there any good tutorial out there ?